# How can I designate unread messages in my mailbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message

I've built a messaging system on my rails 4 app and in the inbox I'm trying to designate unread messages somehow.

The index has a table in it with three columns that display sender, the first 20 characters of message content, and the time that it was sent. The 2nd column, is a link_to so the user can click on it and be taken to the message#show view.

Below is my code, I want to use Bold or Italics to designate the unread messages, but so far haven't been able to figure this out. Would I use an 'if' statement here? Or is the styling something that I add to the CSS stylesheet, and if so, how would I change the html tags in the view to only capture unread messages?

```
<tbody>
      <% @messages.each do |message| %>
        <tr<%= "class-strong" if message.read_at %>>
          <td><%= message.sender.first_name + " " + message.sender.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to truncate(message.content, length: 35), message_path(message.id) %></td>
          <td><% if message.created_at > (Time.now-24.hour) %>
                <%= message.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p") %>
              <% else %>
                <%= message.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering invalid html here:

```
<tr<%= "class-strong" if message.read_at %>>
```

Change it to:

```
<tr class="<%= "class-strong" if message.read_at %>">
```

Comment: No change. Everything functions just fine, except there is no difference in the table rows. should the "class-strong" maybe come somewhere before the <%= tag?